# How do I allow users to drag and drop content on my site and also save their updates?

Tags: html

How do I allow users to drag and drop content on my site and also save their updates? To be more detailed im creating an app for people to build their family tree and by default my program sorts each family member by name but users would like to customize their family tree does anyone know how I can do this. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is what you are looking for [Drag and drop](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/),